# Dynamic configuration for Traefik inside Redis

Tags: redis, traefik

What does the configuration for Traefik inside Redis need to look like and what type of entity does it need to be stored in (e.g. list, hash, bucket). I have not been able to find any documentation and all my experiments have failed so far.